# LatLng variable is not being assigned its latitude and longitude

Tags: android, maps

I'm currently having issues with my android code. My LatLng variable currentLocation is always null and I cannot seem to set it so that it is assigned to the two latitude and longitude values that I get in the onSuccess() listener.

In the method getCurrentLocation(), I get the latitude and longtitude values from the Task, which I then put into a variable `current` I then assign currentLocation, the value of current. I used breakpoints but current is not being assigned to currentLocation

Please see code for reference:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public Location myLocation;
public LatLng currentLocation;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    currentLocation = new LatLng(0,0);

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

}


private void getCurrentLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }

    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location != null){
               myLocation = location;

                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lon = location.getLongitude();
                Log.v("MapsActivity", "Lat: " + latitude + "    Long: " + longitude);

                latitude = lat;
                longitude = lon;
                LatLng current = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                currentLocation = current;
            }
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    getCurrentLocation();
    Log.v("MapsActivity", "Latitude: " + latitude + "    Longitude: " + longitude);
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Your location"));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation,10));



}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
...
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The problem is that the getCurrentLocation() method is asynchronous and when the onMapReady() is executed, the result is not initialized yet.  A solution is to use a callback, so when the onFusedLocation finish, then you will can update the googleMap variable

Comment: How would I implement the callback? (as in the code, I'm new to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a callback between two methods, so when the getCurrentLocation finish, then init the onMapReady logic:

```
class ExampleCallbackClass {

    interface Callback {
        void onFinish();
    }

    void onMapReady() {
        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // Your onMapReady logic
            }
        };

        getCurrentLocation(callback);
    }


       private void getCurrentLocation(Callback callback) {
        // Your logic, and finally:
        callback.onFinish();
    }
}
```